# Mysqli - ошибка с кодировкой при обработке файла

Tags: mysqli

Прописываю в файле код:

```
    $mysqli = NEW mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "onlineForm");

/* проверка соединения */
IF (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}

printf("Изначальная кодировка: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());

/* изменение набора символов на utf8 */
IF (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
  printf("Ошибка при загрузке набора символов utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
  exit();
} ELSE {
  printf("Текущий набор символов: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}

$mysqli->close();

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
  $login = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['login']));
}
```

и при обработке поля выскакивает ошибка: Изначальная кодировка: utf8 Текущий набор символов: utf8
Что за бред? В чём причина?[image: картинка]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была из-за того, что не было обёрнуто подключение к базе в переменную. Обернув в переменную и прописал переменную в real_escape - всё работает нормально. Вопрос остался только с дэбагером. Почему он так отображается?

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','onlineForm1')
or die('ERROR! No connect to DataBase');


if(isset($_POST['login'])){
  $login = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,trim($_POST['login']));
}
```